# Compare each of the column values and return final value based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
col1  col2  col3
 1      2     3
 2      3     NaN
 3      4     NaN
 2      NaN   NaN
 0      2     NaN
```

What I want to do is apply some condition to the column values and return the final result in a new column.

The condition is to assign values based on this order of priority where 2 being the first priority: [2,1,3,0,4]

I tried to define a function to append the final results but wasnt really getting anywhere...any thoughts?

The desired outcome would look something like:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
 1     2     3     2
 2     3     NaN   2
 3     4    NaN    3
 2     NaN   NaN   2
 0     2    NaN    2
```

where col4 is the new column created.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide short example with desired result?

Comment: Hey have edited. Thanks

Comment: What are the conditions based on which you are assigning priority?

Comment: As stated above, the condition is in order of priority: 2,1,3,0,4 where 2 is the highest and 4 being lowest.

Comment: What I don't understand is why does row 2 have 2 as `col4` vs row 3 has `3`? How is this order determined?

Comment: I have determined the order, as stated. for row1, I am comparing 3 values, 1,2,3. Since 2 gets the priority over 1 and 3, the returned value will be 2, appended to col4. For row 2, I am comparing 2 and 3, so 2 will be returned as the final value. For row3, I am comparing 3 and 4, and since 3 has priority over 4, 3 will be returned...and so on. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you may want to get ride of the NaNs:

```
df.fillna(5)
```

and then apply a function to every row to find your value:

```
def func(x,l=[2,1,3,0,4,5]):
    for j in l:
      if(j in x):
         return j

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(list(x)),axis =1)
```

**Output**:

```
     col1   col2    col3    new
  0   1      2        3      2    
  1   2      3        5      2
  2   3      4        5      3
  3   2      5        5      2
  4   0      2        5      2
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little later.

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    for i in [2,1,3,0,4]:
        if i in x.tolist():
            return i
    return np.nan
df["col4"] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

and the Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1   2.0   3.0     2
1     2   3.0   NaN     2
2     3   4.0   NaN     3
3     2   NaN   NaN     2
4     0   2.0   NaN     2
```